# express this is returning null in between functions

Tags: javascript, express

I have created a model in express. i am setting `this` in one function but it seem to return null in another so i have to use `return` instead.

what is the correct way to do this?

```
const Seat = function(seat) {
  this.seat = seat.seat;
  this.seatNumber = seat.seatNumber;
  this.price = seat.price;
  this.available = seat.available;
  this.disabilityAccessible = seat.disabilityAccessible;
};

Seat.findSeat = (key, value) => {
  this.seat = file.find(obj => obj[key] === value);
  return this.seat;
};



Seat.bookSeat = function(seatNumber, result) {
  this.seat = this.findSeat('seatNumber', seatNumber);
  if (this.seat === undefined || Object.keys(this.seat).length === 0) {
    result({ error: true, message: "Seat not found" });
  }
  if(!this.seat.available){
    result({ error: true, message: "Seat unavailable to book" });
  }
  const newSeatData = file.map(row => {
    if (row.seatNumber === seatNumber) {
      row.available = false;
      this.seat = row;
    }
    return row;
  });
  fs.writeFileSync("./model/seatData.json", JSON.stringify(newSeatData,null,2), "utf-8", function(err) {
    if (err) {
      result({ error: true, message: "failed to update booking" });
    }
  });

  result(null, this.seat);
};


module.exports = Seat;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to call those methods on *a seat instance*, they have to be on `Seat.prototype` not on `Seat` itself.

Also note that you possibly call `result(...)` multiple times as you are not terminating the execution of the function when you call it. That might cause problems if the code passing a callback expects the callback to be called once (possibly related to your previous question).

Comment: can you show me example of seat.prototype? I thought `result` is like a `return ;` or i need to pass `return result..;` or `return;` after `result`?

Comment: Yes, you have to `return`. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance